# Jump Point Search jn JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, path-finding

I want to implement a 8-direction path finding algorithm by JavaScript. I found a algorithm, Jump Point Search. I see it's very good but I can't found a simply demo of this algorithm. Anybody can help me?

Comment: never heard of it either, but here's the demo anyways: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jB1IOR5roUM

Comment: It looks like an A* over the space of interesting points but you still have to know which points and paths are interesting: those that are never worth splitting.

Comment: Here's a source code in F#: http://ffogd.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/f-star-pathfinding-with-jump-point.html

Comment: Yeah. That's about it. An A* with intelligent pruning.

Answer (score 0):

You can find [this demo](http://qiao.github.com/PathFinding.js/visual/) helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.